# Catching all possible exceptions while using android videoview

Tags: android, exception, try-catch, android-videoview, ioexception

I am using android [videoview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView) to display a loop of videos, as per our requirement the video loop should continue even if one of the videos gives an error.

To catch any exception, I have included the relevant code in a try-catch block as shown in the below code. However, while testing all scenarios, I gave the wrong path to the [videoview.setVideopath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#setVideoPath(java.lang.String)) but the exception is not caught. I can see in the android studio console that it reports the data source not found error, but catch block does not catch the exception. I also tried implementing `onerrorlistener`, it is also not called when this happens.

Could you please help me, I am attaching the relevant code and exception log, many thanks for your help.

```
 private void DisplayVideo_VideoView(){
    try {
        adplayer = (ResizableVideoView) findViewById(R.id.adplayer);
        String MediaStorePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/Videos";
     //   String videoPath = MediaStorePath + "/" + Root2Util.Videopathlist.get(CurrentMediaIndex).getFileName();
        String videoPath = MediaStorePath + "/1" + Root2Util.Videopathlist.get(CurrentMediaIndex).getFileName();
        //adplayer.setVideoPath(videopath[CurrentMediaIndex]);
        adplayer.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        adplayer.changeVideoSize(Root2Util.SCREEN_WIDTH, Root2Util.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        adplayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        adplayer.start();
        adplayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);

       adplayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                CurrentMediaIndex++;
                //mp.reset();
                if (CurrentMediaIndex == Root2Util.Videopathlist.size()) {
                    CurrentMediaIndex = 0;

                }

                playMedia();
             //   ErrorHandlerAsyncTask ErrorTask=new ErrorHandlerAsyncTask();
             //   ErrorTask.execute((Object)getApplicationContext(),(Object)String.valueOf(what));

                return false;
            }

        });
      } catch(Exception e) {

        ErrorHandlerAsyncTask ErrorTask=new ErrorHandlerAsyncTask();
        ErrorTask.execute((Object)getApplicationContext(),(Object)e.getMessage());
    }
```

Exception log from the console :

```
W/VideoView: Unable to open content: /storage/emulated/0/Download/Videos/1f0a9106d-d7d5-470c- 
    b287-3e3cad7d13fb.mp4
    java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1091)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1065)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1019)
    at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:352)
    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2100(VideoView.java:72)
    at android.widget.VideoView$7.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:628)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:580)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.java:256)
    at root2tech.cloudplayer.HomepageActivity.DisplayVideo_VideoView(HomepageActivity.java:728)
    at root2tech.cloudplayer.HomepageActivity.playMedia(HomepageActivity.java:958)
    at root2tech.cloudplayer.HomepageActivity.access$200(HomepageActivity.java:78)
    at root2tech.cloudplayer.HomepageActivity$5.run(HomepageActivity.java:571)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:935)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730)
```

Comment: What is `ErrorHandlerAsyncTask ` - if it is your code then post it.  The exception likely is caught and that code then displays the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just faced a similar issue, I needed to use a VideoView to play the video from a URL without any knowledge of if the URL was a valid video or not. I understand why you're asking about catching every exception as well. My VideoView would print out an IOException and another which I can't quite remember at the moment of this answer. To fix this, I used a very similar code to yours but in a different order. The setOnErrorListener is what solved my issue for me but I placed my OnErrorListener directly after my VideoPlayer initialization and before the setVideoPath.

This works because the setVideoPath is where the errors are handled, unfortunately, VideoView will print these errors to the log but it will not throw anything to crash the app (which I don't agree with or like one bit). Because of this, your setOnErrorListener should at least go before you set the path or there will be nothing for it to catch as the error would have been thrown already (The errors aren't thrown on start oddly enough.

To apply my solution to your code, I would change it to this:

```
private void DisplayVideo_VideoView(){
    //initialize adplayer
    adplayer = (ResizableVideoView) findViewById(R.id.adplayer);
    //begin listening for errors
    adplayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            CurrentMediaIndex++;
            if (CurrentMediaIndex == Root2Util.Videopathlist.size()) {
                CurrentMediaIndex = 0;
            }
            playMedia();
        
            return false;
        }

    });
    //build variables for readability
    String MediaStorePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/Videos";
    String videoPath = MediaStorePath + "/1" + Root2Util.Videopathlist.get(CurrentMediaIndex).getFileName();
    //set path - If there is an issue with videoPath, the error should be thrown here
    adplayer.setVideoPath(videoPath);
    //final adplayer customizations
    adplayer.changeVideoSize(Root2Util.SCREEN_WIDTH, Root2Util.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    adplayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //begin the adplayer
    adplayer.start();
    adplayer.setKeepScreenOn(true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good style of code to catch a raw [Exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), it is too broad to handle different error cases. However, for most of the IO operations [IOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is the base exception, it is recommended to catch this.

As per [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html), we also need to consider IO operations can throw [IOError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOError.html). `Error` is not under the hierarchy of `Exception`, but both `IOException` and `Error` share [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) as the base class. With this consideration, you can write your try-catch block as:

```
try {
    // Your code
} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
        // handle IOException here
    } else if (throwable instanceof Error) {
        if (t instanceof IOError) {
            // handle IOError here
        }
    } else {
        //This else will be reached only if you have any custom exceptions
    }
}
```

For more readability of the code, you can use multiple catch blocks:

```
try {
    // Your code
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    // handle IOException here
} catch (IOError ioError) {
    // handle IOError here
}
```

Also, you can add `throws` clause to your method if you want to handle these exceptions later:

```
public void displayVideo() throws Throwable {
    // Your code here
}
```

**Note:** This is not the perfect solution to capture all exceptions for your scenario. But, since your code also includes IO operations on the file, hence have used the above examples to explain how you can possibly implement your exception handling.